# Spring Test with dependency Injection of real objects and mocks

Tags: java, spring, testing, mocking

I have a test use case in which based on a boolean property we decide which one of 2 Spring Beans to create upon application startup.
For simplicity, let's call them `ProfileServiceA` and `ProfileServiceB`.
When the boolean property is set to `false` (the default) it creates `ProfileServiceA` and when it's `true` it creates `ProfileServiceB`.
This is done inside of a configuration class annotated with `@Configuration`.

My test is pretty simple, I want to verify which one of the Beans is loaded in the Spring Context when our application is starting based on that property.
For each of those Beans, when we create them, the constructor gets multiple objects in order to be instantiated.
Most of the objects I have annotated with the `@MockBean` because they are only being pointed to in the constructor like we usually do with Dependency Injection and that's not a problem for me.
One of those properties is not only pointed at in the constructor but is actually being used to build one of the fields.
in the constructor of ProfileService we do something like this:

```
this.url = securityProperties.getProfile().getProtocol() + "://" + securityProperties.getProfile().getHost() + ":" + securityProperties.getProfile().getPort() + "/" + securityProperties.getProfile().getEndpoint();
```

The `SecurityProperties` class has the **inner static class** `Profile`, So when the application context starts to load and this Bean is being instantiated in the constructor (even before the method annotated with `@Before`) I fail on NullPointerException because the object `Profile` is still null (The `SecurityProperties` is not because it's annotated with `@MockBean`).

The SecurityProperties and its inner static class Profile are not defined as Beans but still, I tried to set the Profile object inside of the test class to be also `@MockBean` or `@Mock` but this didn't solve the issue.

I figured that I probably need to inject "real" Objects into the context but I couldn't find a wiki/docs on how to inject "real" objects WITH Mocked ones to an Autowired Spring Bean.

The SecurityProperties is not a Spring Bean but a regular data object (POJO).

Comment: So you don't use Dependency Injection to get a ProfileService but call the constructor yourself? Could use the @Profile("myProfile") annotation on the service to automatically create the needed service with autowired dependencies?

Comment: I do use dependency injection. In the test class, the ProfileService is annotated with "Autowired". The fields that are supposed to be injected into the constructor of that Bean are all annotated with "MockBean" (like the SecurityProperties class). They are not null in the constructor, only the Profile class which is an inner static class inside of SecurityProperties.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the [BeanPostProcessor interface](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/BeanPostProcessor.html) in your test code. In the implementation of  `postProcessBeforeInitialization`, if the current bean name is `securityProperties` (or whatever name your SecurityProperties bean has) then mock the behavior of `SecurityProperties::getProfile()` to return an actual Profile instance to avoid the NPE.

This works because `ProfileService` depends on `SecurityProperties` so the latter will be initiated first and right after that your postProcessBeforeInitialization will be called, right before the instantiation of `ProfileService`

Comment: I believe this would not solve my issue, I edited my question by saying that the SecurityProperties class is not an actual Spring Bean. Adding an interface to this class only to support one of our tests doesn't seem like the right approach. I really am a bit confused on why it's a bit hard to inject "real" Objects with "mocked" ones to the constructor of a Spring Bean.

Comment: Like I said, your test class should implement that interface, not the SecurityProperties class, because those methods get called for all beans in tha app context. But if SecurityProperties is not a bean this won't work. I wonder why it's not a bean. Put more details in your question about that class, how it gets instatiated and initialized, how it gets passed to the service. They say that if a component becomes difficult to test it usually means the design needs to be improved. You could think about that too